# How do I remove the -C parameter from cvs update in a Hudson build

Tags: hudson, cvs

I can't find where I can configure the parameters that hudson uses in CVS checkout and update.

I have a situation where I modify build properties file locally before I kick off a hudson build. However because the cvs update contains a '-C' it overwrites my local changes. Do you know of a way where I can remove this?

Any help much appreciated,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing me. How do you change the build properties locally before kicking off the build? If I need to do something like that, I first get the code from my SCM and then run a script to make changes (like changing the build properties) and than start the actual build process (usually by kicking off maven or ant). The whole purpose of a CI (what Hudson is supposed to be used for) is to have a reproducible build. Manual steps during a build usually do not count as reproducible.